# My fitbit isn't picking up on my Windows 10 bluetooth settings

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, windows-10, bluetooth

I got the new Fitbit app on my Windows 10 laptop last night. I want to be able to sync my Charge with my laptop, so I says that I need to go to settings and pair my Fitbit with my laptop. My Fitbit isn't showing up in the bluetooth list. Instead, it is showing up as unknown. [image: Bluetooth settings]

My laptop uses Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R) chip with Microsoft Bluetooth and Bluetooth LE Enumerators. Is there a remedy.

My laptop is a Dell inspiron 15R mid-2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found on Fitbit that I need to plug in my dongle. Now where the heck did I put it?